# having trouble writing objects into a txt file

Tags: python

At the end of this code I am trying to write the updated values of the 8 values I have (starting with VIN, going through Rentals) for two different objects back into a new txt file. There should be two lines in the file, one for each object, each with 8 values separated by commas. However, with my current code, all that is going into the txt file is the two objects' VINs. They are 101 and 102, so the file simply reads '101102'. Does anyone know where my problem is and how I can make it two lines of 8 comma separated values?

```
class Fleet(object):
    fleetcount = 0
    car_desc = "DMC DeLorean"
    daily_rate = 100
    maxfleet = 10
    
    def get_vin(self):
        return self.__vin
    def get_type(self):
        return self.__type
    def get_year(self):
        return self.__year
    def get_odometer(self):
        return self.__odometer
    def set_odometer(self, miles):
        if miles>self.__odometer:
            self.__odometer = miles
    def get_r_miles(self):
        return self.__r_miles
    def get_r_days(self):
        return self.__r_days
    def get_rentals(self):
        return self.__rentals
    
    def __init__(self, vin, typ, year, odometer, color, r_miles = 0, r_days = 0, rentals = 0 ):
        self.__vin = vin
        self.__type = typ
        self.__year = year
        self.color = color
        self.__odometer = odometer
        self.__r_miles = r_miles
        self.__r_days = r_days
        self.__rentals = rentals
        Fleet.fleetcount += 1
        
    def process_rental(self, new_odo, days):
        self.__rentals += 1
        self.__r_days += days
        self.__r_miles += (new_odo - self.__odometer)
        self.set_odometer(new_odo)
        
    def calc_bill(self,new_odo, days): 
        return days * Fleet.daily_rate
    
    def calc_age(self, curr_yr):
        age = curr_yr - self.__year
        return age
    
    def sell_car(self,curr_yr):
        if self.calc_age(curr_yr)>3 or self.__odometer>50000:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        
    def print_summary(self):
        print("VIN:", self.__vin, "Make:",Fleet.car_desc, "Year:", self.__year, "Color:", self.color, "Odometer:", self.__odometer, "\n")
        
    def print_metrics(self, curr_yr):
        age = curr_yr - self.__year
        rmpy = self.__r_miles/age
        rdpy = self.__r_days/age
        rpy = self.__rentals/age
        mpr = self.__r_miles/self.__rentals
        dpr = self.__r_days/self.__rentals
        print("METRICS FOR CAR WITH VIN", self.__vin, "ARE AS FOLLOWS")
        print("Average rental miles per year:", rmpy)
        print("Average rental days per year:", rdpy)
        print("Average times rented per year:", rpy)
        print("Average miles per rental:", mpr)
        print("Average days per rental:", dpr, "\n")
    
    def fleet_left(self):
        remaining = Fleet.maxfleet - Fleet.fleetcount
        if remaining>0:
            return remaining
        else:
            return 0
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__vin + "," + self.__type + "," + self.__year + "," + self.__odometer + "," + self.color + "," + self.__r_miles + "," + self.__r_days + "," + self.__rentals
        
class Truck(Fleet):
    daily_rate = 85
    mile_rate = .5
    def calc_bill(self, new_odo, days): 
        miles = new_odo - self.get_odometer()
        return (miles * Truck.mile_rate) + (days * Truck.daily_rate)

 # Main Program for 9B
with open("fleet.txt", "r") as myfile:
    next(myfile)
    fleet = {}
    for line in myfile:
         v, ty, y, o, c, rm, rd, r = line.strip().split(",")
         if ty == "C":
            fleet[v] = Fleet(v, ty, int(y), int(o), c, int(rm), int(rd), int(r))
         else:
            fleet[v] = Truck(v, ty, int(y), int(o), c, int(rm), int(rd), int(r))

totalrev = 0
with open("transaction.txt", "r") as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        trans = line.strip().split(",")
        if trans[1] == "R":
            totalrev += fleet[trans[0]].calc_bill(int(trans[2]), int(trans[3]))
            fleet[trans[0]].process_rental(int(trans[2]), int(trans[3]))
        elif trans[1] == "S":
            fleet[trans[0]].set_odometer(int(trans[2]))
        elif trans[1] == "P":
            fleet[trans[0]].color = trans[2]
            
yr = int(input("What is the current year? "))
sell_list = []
for obj in fleet:
    if fleet[obj].sell_car(yr) == True:
        sell_list.append(obj.get_vin())

rem = fleet[trans[0]].fleet_left()

print("Total Revenue:", totalrev)
print("VINs of vehicles that should be sold:", sell_list)
print("Additional number of vehicles that can be acquired:", rem)

with open("updated_fleet.txt", "w") as myfile:
    for obj in fleet:
        outline = obj.__str__()
        myfile.write(outline)
    myfile.close()
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Pro Tip: call `str(obj)` rather than `obj.__str__()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fleet.values()` in the loop to get values from the dict instead of keys and `\n` in the `.write()` for line feed:

```
with open(r"c:\test\updated_fleet.txt", "w") as myfile:
    for val in fleet.values():
        outline = val.__str__()
        myfile.write(outline + '\n')
    # myfile.close() # is redundant because it within the 'with'
```